# How to use hyperledger getnative API

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I came across the getNative API through which one call chaincode from Hyperledger composer. See here: https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/3120

Can someone please tell me exactly how does this work? Say if I have a very simple chaincode with a getter and setter, can I invoke those from the JS code in composer

Answer (score 11):

To call the Hyperledger Fabric API in a transaction processor function of `composer`, the function `getNativeAPI` must be called. `getNativeAPI` allow users to call directly of the Fabric `shim API` which provides the APIs for application developers to implement "Smart Contracts" for the Hyperledger Fabric backend, also known as `Chaincodes`.

Here is a sample example of using `getNativeAPI` in composer which called the Hyperledger Fabric API function `getHistoryForKey` to returns the history of a specified asset as an iterator. The transaction processor function then stores the returned data in an array.

```
async function simpleNativeHistoryTransaction (transaction) {    
    const id = transaction.assetId;
    const nativeSupport = transaction.nativeSupport;

    const nativeKey = getNativeAPI().createCompositeKey('Asset:systest.transactions.SimpleStringAsset', [id]);
    const iterator = await getNativeAPI().getHistoryForKey(nativeKey);
    let results = [];
    let res = {done : false};
    while (!res.done) {
        res = await iterator.next();

        if (res && res.value && res.value.value) {
            let val = res.value.value.toString('utf8');
            if (val.length > 0) {
                results.push(JSON.parse(val));
            }
        }
        if (res && res.done) {
            try {
                iterator.close();
            }
            catch (err) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*Remember: The `getState` and `putState` Hyperledger Fabric API functions will bypass the Hyperledger Composer access control rules.*

**Some resource :**

- [Fabric Chainode](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/chaincode.html)
- [Fabric Shim](https://fabric-shim.github.io/index.html)
- [Composer Transaction](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/next/reference/js_scripts.html)

Hope these will help you to understand.

Comment: +1 @mohammadjh: just adding a link to the functions (for the reader) that you can call from `getnativeAPI()` -> https://fabric-shim.github.io/ChaincodeStub.html feel free to add it to your answer (albeit you provide the main index page already).

Answer (score 3):

There's Composer chaincode (written in javascript) and Fabric's native chaincode (written in GO). If you want to invoke the chaincode deployed by Composer tools (as a part of a Business Network Definition), you don't need to call native API. You'll need it for low-level calls like getting information on a particular transaction.

Comment: When we deploy the native chaincode, we see a sandbox container for the peer. And recently, we know that Fabric has started supporting JS chaincode. Is the composer chaincode -> same as js chaincode? Or is the composer chaincode another container which comes up, in the docker network, which will invoke the generic container of Fabric native chaincode ?

The point is, how many containers comes up per peer when we deploy a Composer chaincode ? 1 or 2 ?

Comment: Composer is not related to docker containers at all. All containers are related to the Fabric -- peers, couchdb, and SA. Each peer is in one container, as always.

If you're familiar with Web programming, then native chaincode (js or GO) is like parsing a raw request. You take the raw data, parse it into URL, method, headers etc, and handle it based on this. Composer chaincode looks like you're using a Web framework, so you have multiple functions each handling its own route/method. Plus, queries and ACLs are purely declarative.