# How to update a shared asset of two hyperledger networks?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I have developed two participants in two different hyperledger composer networks(A and B). A and B have a common asset. Since the asset is common, both networks must be able to update the shared asset. I have developed the shared asset in A, and I want to update it by B. B can read the asset by following the hyperledger tutorial[[1](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/invoke-composer-network)], and also it can invoke low level commands of hyperledger fabric by its APIs[[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49535602/how-to-use-hyperledger-getnative-api?noredirect=1&lq=1)] but I do not know how B can update the shared asset.

Answer (score 1):

if the business networks are on the same channel in the same Fabric network (not different Fabric networks), then you can use invokeChaincode (as referred to in that 1st tutorial) to do an update call that would be atomic (ie all update(s) occur, or none at all, in the transaction function). You need to read up more on invokeChaincode usage in that regard.

Beyond that, it becomes a complex question, such as business networks on different Fabric channels or, in different Fabric networks - suffice to say, it would not be atomic in that case.

Comment: Thank you Paul. I used resolveResourceInRegistry method but it was not worked. My DSL and sript is:
namespace org.example.mynetwork
asset Commodity identified by tradingSymbol {
    o String tradingSymbol
    o String description
    o String mainExchange
    o Double quantity
}
transaction Trade {
    --> Commodity commodity
}
async function tradeCommodity(trade) {
 const otherNetworkData = await getNativeAPI().invokeChaincode('other-tutorial-network', ['resolveResourceInRegistry', 'Asset', 'org.example.mynetwork.Commodity', trade.commodity.tradingSymbol], 'composerchannel');
}

Comment: I do know that resolve, resolveAll() are not available in Transaction runtime (client only) - so may be a similar thing? https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/3454